# Running a set of regular expressions in VI

Tags: vim

I have a list of regular expressions I would like to run on my C code files. They are simple formatting stuff and would save me trouble while my code is reviewed.

Here they are

this removes 2 or more blank lines in a single blank line

```
:%s/\n\{3,}/\r\r/e
```

this add missing space at the end of the comment eg /* blah blah*/  to /* blah blah */

```
:%s/\([^ *]\)\*\//\1 \*\//gc
```

this add missing space at the start of the comment eg /*blah blah*/  to /* blah blah*/  note that it ignores /**

```
:%s/\/\*\([^  *]\)/\/\* \1/gc
```

removes blank lines after opening brace {

```
:%s/{\s*$\n\{2,}/{\r/gc
```

removes blank lines before closing brace }

```
:%s/\n\{2,}\(\s*\)}/\r\1}/gc
```

in comments adds a space after comma if missing TODO throws and error E16 if no patterns match

```
:g/\/\*/ ,/\*\// s/,\([^ ]\)/, \1/gc
```

I have saved these in a file called fix.txt. Is there a way I can run them from within VI one after the other? something like

```
:run fix.txt ?
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to execute:

`:source fix.txt`

See `:help :source`.

Answer (score 0):

```
" put this function in your vimrc file and call them with <leader>f 
" to more information read :help leader
" also read :help keepjumps
fun! FixSourceCode()
  :%s/\n\{3,}/\r\r/e
  :%s/\([^ *]\)\*\//\1 \*\//gc
  :%s/\/\*\([^  *]\)/\/\* \1/gc
  :%s/{\s*$\n\{2,}/{\r/gc
  :%s/\n\{2,}\(\s*\)}/\r\1}/gc
  :g/\/\*/ ,/\*\// s/,\([^ ]\)/, \1/gc
Endfun
nmap <silent> <leader>f :keepjumps call FixSourceCode()<cr>
```